# Sign applets from code

Tags: java, applet, java-7, jarsigner

I have to deploy my signed applet in several clients and whith java 1.7.0.55 it's necessary to include in manifest the attribute Caller-Allowable-Codebase with the caller domain. Before this version I can indicate an * to indicate any domain. More info https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/jdk_8u5_and_jdk_7u55

I Want sign the applet when I distribute it. Are there any way to sign applets by java code?

One way is call jarsigner in console from java code, but I don't like this solution. I´m thinking in do it by code, for example calling a class or implementing signature with BouncyCastle.

It's possible?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why? You only have to do it once per deployment. Just build it into your build process.

Comment: I have to deploy my applet in several clients and whith java 1.7.0.55  I have to include in manifest in Caller-Allowable-Codebase the caller domain, like you can see in https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/jdk_8u5_and_jdk_7u55